# Changing state for pressed item only

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native app I have a function that changes the state of the pressed item from false to true, but the issue is that it's changing the state for all of the items not only the pressed one, i want when i press to change it for the pressed one only inside my FlatList, here is the code:

**Initial state:**

```
state={pressed: false}
```

**Function:**

```
changeItem = async item => {this.setState({ pressed: true });};
```

**Rendering item and binding the function:**

```
_renderItem({ item, index }) {
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeItem.bind(this, item)}>
     <Text> Click me </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   );
}
```

**FlatList:**

```
<FlatList data={this.state.items}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor.bind(this)}
          renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: Every item needs a pressed prop. You can change your state from simple boolean to an array of boolean, one for each item of your flatlist

Comment: @Milore can you post how as an answer please?

Comment: `it's changing the state for all of the items`, where is the other itens? Are you using a `FlatList` or something like that? If yes, Please provide the rest of the code.

Comment: @Vencovsky updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a list of items, but all of then have the same state.

You need a list of items (an array) but you also need an array of the items state.

So instead of `state = { pressed: false }` you need `state = { pressed: []}`

And when rendering the items you need to pass the index of the pressed button:

```
_renderItem({ item, index }) {
   return this.state.pressed[index] &&
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeItem.bind(this, item, index)}>
          <Text> Click me </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

And Update the state only in the selected index

```
changeItem = async (item, index) => {
    let itensPressed = this.state.pressed
    itensPressed[index] = itensPressed[index] ? false : true
    this.setState({ pressed: itensPressed })
}
```

But there is something better than doing this.

I see that you are getting the `items` from the `state` so maybe you want to update the `items` array an not create another variable.

This depends on how is your `this.state.items` is coming and if you can or can't have the `isPressed` value in that array.

If you show how your `items` is coming, I can create a better answer.

Comment: this answer still changes the state for all of the items, I'm getting the items from fetching a call, and showing them conditionally based on the pressed state

Comment: Show where in the code you do this: `showing them conditionally based on the pressed state`

Comment: Can you store if the item is pressed in the `this.state.items` ?

Comment: and i show them conditionally inside the render item like this `{!this.state.pressed ?  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeItem.bind(this, item, index)}>
     <Text> Click me </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity> : null}`

Comment: @MonicaJennings you need to check `this.state.pressed[index]`. See my edits

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple button that have its own state. you need to make an array pressed boolean, in state so that each element in an array has its own pressed state.

Do it like this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

sampleData = [
  {key: 0, pressed: false},
  {key: 1, pressed: false},
  {key: 2, pressed: false}
]

export default class Example extends Component {

  state={
    data: sampleData
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  changeItem(item)
  {
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
      prevState.data[item.key] = { ...item, pressed: !item.pressed}
      return{
        ...prevState,
        data: [...prevState.data]
      }
      });
  };  



  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.key;

  _renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeItem.bind(this,item)}>
      <Text> Click me </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )

 }

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state
      return (
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
      />
      )
    }
  }
```

i just create an array of object contains key and pressed property and passed it to state.data

check console log, to see the output state.